# R: find Index of data frame with non-unique/duplicated values

Tags: r, indexing, duplicates

I want to extract some values out of a vector, modify them and put them back at the original position. 
I have been searching a lot and tried different approaches to this problem. I'm afraid this might be really simple but I'm not seeing it yet.

---

Creating a vector and convert it to a dataframe with. Also creating a empty dataframe for the results.

```
hight <- c(5,6,1,3)
hight_df <- data.frame("ID"=1:length(hight), "hight"=hight)
hight_min_df <- data.frame()
```

Extract for every pair of values the smaller value with corresponding ID.

```
for(i in 1:(length(hight_df[,2])-1))
{
  hight_min_df[i,1] <- which(grepl(min(hight_df[,2][i:(i+1)]), hight_df[,2]))
  hight_min_df[i,2] <- min(hight_df[,2][i:(i+1)])
}
```

Modify the extracted values and aggregate same IDs by higher value. At the end writing the modified values back.

```
hight_min_df[,2] <- hight_min_df[,2]+20  
adj_hight <- aggregate(x=hight_min_df[,2],by=list(hight_min_df[,1]), FUN=max)
hight[adj_hight[,1]] <- adj_hight[,2]
```

---

This works perfectly as long a I have only uniqe values in `hight`.
How can I run this script with a vector like this: `hight <- c(5,6,1,3,5)`?

Comment: What is the expected output if `hight <- c(5,6,1,3,5)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright there's a lot to unpack here. Instead of looping, I would suggest piping functions with `dplyr`. Read the vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) - it is an outstanding resource and an excellent approach to data manipulation in R.

So using `dplyr` we can rewrite your code like this:

```
library(dplyr)
hight <- c(5,6,1,3,5) #skip straight to the test case
hight_df <- data.frame("ID"=1:length(hight), "hight"=hight)

adj_hight <- hight_df %>%
  #logic psuedo code: if the last hight (using lag() function),
  # going from the first row to the last,
  # is greater than the current rows hight, take the current rows value. else
  # take the last rows value
  mutate(subst.id = ifelse(lag(hight) > hight, ID, lag(ID)), 
         subst.val = ifelse(lag(hight) > hight, hight, lag(hight)) + 20) %>%
  filter(!is.na(subst.val)) %>% #remove extra rows
  select(subst.id, subst.val) %>% #take just the columns we want
  #grouping - rewrite of your use of aggregate
  group_by(subst.id) %>% 
  summarise(subst.val = max(subst.val)) %>%
  data.frame(.)

#tying back in
hight[adj_hight[,1]] <- adj_hight[,2]
print(hight)
```

Giving:

```
[1] 25  6 21 23  5
```